# Term-set-escape-char problem

Tags: emacs, elisp, eshell

When I start M-x eshell  it gives me message "term-set-escape-char: Key sequence M-x starts with non-prefix key".  It doesn't give me prompt in the *eshell* window.

eshell-prompt-regexp is

"^[^#$\n]* [#$] ".

eshell-prompt-function is:

(lambda nil
  (concat
   (abbreviate-file-name
    (eshell/pwd))
   (if
       (=
        (user-uid)
        0)
       " # " " $ ")))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce this. You don't indicate what your hardware platform is or whether the problem still occurs when you start with just a minimal init file. I googled and found a similar bug report here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.bugs/15859. That user was on Windows and the issue was corrected by removing a key binding that they had in their init file.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Linux: ( 2.6.18-128.4.1.el5 , x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). I read the article you mentioned and by tinkerig with my .emacs file, I found that "(one-key-default-setup-keys)". was causing the problem. After commenting this command, it worked properly.